# SOAP requests without namespaces result in null after JAXB unmarshaling

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

We must reverse-engineer a SOAP endpoint from an existing WSDL.  The existing clients cannot change, neither can the WSDL.  Using JAXB and wsdl2java we created our java classes - we have no XJB config at the moment.  Then, when testing the resulting SOAP endpoint with a SOAPUI-generated client everything works.  When we send in existing client SOAP requests however, the "web" namespaced-fields map to null in the resulting Java objects.

Investigation has shown that the working SOAPUI-generated requests have namespace information throughout the *complex* elements of the request.  E.g.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                
                  xmlns:web="http://com/myco/myapp/webservice/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <web:create>
            <web:CreateRequest>
                <TransactionID>ABABABABAB</TransactionID>
                <Carrier>XX</Carrier>
                <web:DispenseDetails>
                    <ServiceName>235495484</ServiceName>
                    <ServiceOption>Packet</ServiceOption>
                </web:DispenseDetails>
            </web:CreateRequest>
        </web:create>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The existing requests don't, though the namespace is defined in the create element:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <create xmlns="http://com/myco/myapp/webservice/">
            <CreateRequest>
                <TransactionID>ABABABABAB</TransactionID>
                <Carrier>XX</Carrier>
                <DispenseDetails>
                    <ServiceName>235495484</ServiceName>
                    <ServiceOption>Packet</ServiceOption>
                </DispenceDetails>
            </CreateRequest>
        </create>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When we add the "myco" namespace information manually to the existing requests (i.e. we update it to look like the working one above, removing the xmlns in create and adding the web ns declaration and tag prefixes etc), these then map through to objects as required and everything works.  Doing the same at This info at  tag level (e.g. ) doesn't seem to cascade down to child-elements as we anticipated either.

Note: The WSDL does have a target-namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"      
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"   
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  
             xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
             xmlns:y="http://com/myco/myapp/webservice/" 
             xmlns:ns="http://com/myco/myapp/webservice/envelope" 
    <types>     
        <xs:schema 
              targetNamespace="http://com/myco/myapp/webservice/
    ...
```

We're guessing that we may be able to use some XJB config to provide more information when the classes are generated, thereby making the unmarshaling spring successfully into life, but have been unable to find the specific tweaks to add. (We only have a single WSDL and no additional XSDs.)

Finally, our Plan B is to pre-process the requests with an XSL-transform to add the namespace information, but this seems like a bit of a bodge.  Finally, to complete the picture, we're using a Camel-route behind a CXF SOAP endpoint - hence the thought to drop back to XSL before we unmarshal. We'd rather not do this unless we really have to.

Comment: I believe that the wsdl contain in schema, see how the targetnamespace is set.

Comment: Thank @Rao. The WSDL does contain a target namespace information. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Looks like 2nd sample from your post is valid one and 1st one does not per my understanding. How did you create these requests? And what are the options that you using while generating classes?

Comment: We've created the request using SOAP-UI. Both requests are well-formed XML's however as the 2nd request does not have the 'web:' namespace in front of certain tags JAXB fails silently by not mapping the xml-elements to the Java object fields.

Comment: Did you by any chance figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Instead dropped back to Plan-B described above.